# Facebook Open Graph Protocol Lint Debugger Error - You have <meta> tags outside your <head>

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i have a facebook tab that i am attempting to place a send button into (standard FB plugin). i want to control the title and description via open graph, so i followed the current FB instructions to do that.

the open graph data just won't show up in the "send" plugin. passing the page through the FB debugger renders this error: "You have meta tags outside your head" and that's why they aren't working, according to it.

the problem is - i have scoured the source of the page and there are no meta tags outside of the head. furthermore, the page passes through the validator with no errors regarding misplaced meta tags (which it would find). the only errors rendered in the validator are regarding FB's use of non-standard meta attributes. no markup errors, no meta tags outside of the head.

so, at a loss. help: appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a link to your page?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and traced the issue to Debugger not parsing my document properly because I had NOSCRIPT tags in the HEAD.  This is valid in HTML5 (which I was using) but not in HTML 4.01.  It appears that the Facebook debugger hasn't caught up with HTML5 tag validation yet.